# Trackview or timeline in Naudio

Tags: c#, naudio

How can I use trackview or timeline in Naudio in C#?

Here is my code and it's not working.

I want to see my line going as track is playing.

```
 NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(open.FileName));
                customWaveViewer2.WaveStream = pcm;
                stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
                trackView1.NowTime = stream.CurrentTime;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `TrackView` and `TimeLine` are not completed controls, and you would be better off writing your own custom control to place a vertical line at a position that represents the now playing time.

You would probably be best using a timer to invalidate your custom wave viewer, and in the Paint method, drawing a vertical line that represents the current play time.

Comment: got any example maybe? I have never beed drawing yet